# Alternative to IML? Running SAS Viya without IML and need to merge covariance matrices of two non-nested clutsters

Tags: matrix, sas, cluster-analysis, covariance

I'm running the SAS Viya environment and do not have access to IML. However, I need to use the following code, or something similar, to calculate standard errors accurately by combining the covariance matrices. The code comes from the following paper (you can download the paper as pdf if you like and the code is in appendix A): https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/165/4/453/109343.

Here's my question: Is there another way to combine the covariance matrices in SAS not using IML?

Below is sample SAS code to fit a logistic regression model to a binary outcome Y, adjusting for the correlation within two nonnested clusters using GEEs. Note that the clustering variable C1C2ID may be created by concatenating C1ID and C2ID in a data step using the command "C1C2ID = C1ID || ‘|’ || C2ID;".

```
%macro gee(n=1,cluster=C1);
proc genmod data=a descending; 
class &cluster; 
model y = x/dist=binomial; 
repeated subject=&cluster/type=indep ecovb; 
ods output GEEEmpPEst=beta GEERCov=V&n; 
quit; 
%mend; 
%gee(n=1,cluster=C1ID); 
%gee(n=2,cluster=C2ID); 
%gee(n=3,cluster=C1C2ID);

The covariance matrices may be read into PROC IML to combine and to calculate the corrected standard errors for the regression coefficients:

proc iml; use V1; 
read all var{rowname}; 
read all var(rowname) into V1; close V1; use V2; 
read all var(rowname) into V2; close V2; use V3; 
read all var(rowname) into V3; close V3; V=V1+V2-V3; SE=sqrt(vecdiag(V)); print SE;
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Sean

Answer (score 0):

The `Proc DS2` [`MATRIX`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=ds2ref&docsetTarget=n1jn2dmm6yc2ixn1ay2lljt69w4b.htm&locale=en) package has many methods for performing matrix operations.

- ABS , ADD,
  ALL_AND , ALL_EQ , ALL_GE , ALL_GT , ALL_LE , ALL_LT , ALL_NE , ALL_OR , AND , ANY_AND , ANY_EQ , ANY_GE , ANY_GT , ANY_LE , ANY_LT , ANY_NE , ANY_OR , COLS , COPY
  DET , EDIV , EMAX , EMIN , EMOD , EMULT , EPOW , EQ , EXP , FLOOR , GE , GT , IN , INVERSE , LE , LOG
  LT ,
  MULT , NE , OR , OUT , ROWS , SQRT , SUB , TOARRAY , TOVARARRAY , TRANS

`Proc MCMC`

> provides you with a number of CALL routines for performing simple matrix operations on declared arrays

- ADDMATRIX, CHOL, DET, ELEMMULT, FILLMATRIX, IDENTITY, INV, MULT, SUBTRACTMATRIX,
  TRANSPOSE, ZEROMATRIX